# will adding new content script disable chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an existing chrome extension in chrome web store. I know that adding new permissions will disable my extension to old users once they upgrade. So for new permissions, i use optional permissions.

Now I need to add a new content_script js file under existing place

OLD:

```
{
    "js": ["scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "scripts/myscript.js"],
    "matches" : ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

NEW:

```
{
    "js": ["scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js", "scripts/newscript.min.js", "scripts/myscript.js"],
    "matches" : ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Will this disable my chrome extension for old users once they upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you already have permission for all sites, upgrading with permission for all sites will not disable your extension.